# How to convert a folder of files on a Mac to PDF?

Tags: mac, pdf, software-rec

I have a folder of files that I want to convert to PDF.  What is the best way on the mac to automate this?

Comment: What kind of files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[deskUNPDF PDF Converter](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/productivity_tools/deskunpdfpdfconverter.html) :Convert and edit the contents of PDF documents with deskUNPDF. Easily and quickly convert PDF’s into Word (.doc), Open Office (.odt), Excel (.xls), HTML, and many more.

[PDF Converter 1.1](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/18084) : Open Automator and select the PDF icon you will see PDF Converter. You can combine with other actions to integrate a complete task and save as a workflow. The PDF Converter includes a workflow file. After you install it in a proper location, you then have the ability to use Contextual Menu to convert files to PDF format

Answer (score 4):

There is a [tutorial](http://www.maciverse.com/automator-tip-of-the-week-3-convert-word-documents-to-pdf.html) for converting .doc files using automator.

Also, there is a fairly new [Automator Action](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/converttopdf_mauriziominelli.html) that converts text files to PDF.